# How to delete entitlement process in salesforce?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I am really facing an issue for deleting the entitlement process from UI. Because it shows some dependency being with the other although I removed it that.

I have the following questions on entitlement and milestone. Could someone please reply ?

1. Can we delete the entitlement process using SOQL query if unable to delete it from UI?
2. How can we deploy the Milestones and Deployment process? Is it possible to deploy using change set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we delete the entitlement process using SOQL query if unable to delete it from UI?

If you can delete from UI, then only you can delete from SOQL. If any dependent records (milestones, entitlement etc) exist, then Entitlement Process cannot be deleted. You can clone and create a new version and make one version as active.

> How can we deploy the Milestones and Deployment process? Is it possible to deploy using change set ?

Yes, those can be deployed through change sets.

[image: outbound change set]